# AVFoundation - Process each image separately

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation

I'm using AVFoundation and the AVCaptureSession class to record my screen. The thing is, I don't want to write the recording to a file, I want to send each frame over a network.

I've gotten to the point where I can easily start/stop a recording and write it to a file. Is there a way to process each frame individually and send them over a network connection to be processed by another application?

The only examples I can find assume you always want to write to a file.

I think that code samples from my project are mostly irrelevant, as my project is a near carbon copy of the screen recorder example from Apple, found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html

I'm developing this application for Mac OSX, not iOS by the way.

Comment: If you want to process an image, why do you even need to develop a desktop application?  Wouldn't be better if you just develop a web application accessed by a web browser?

Comment: No. It's not 'an image', it's every frame of the video. I need to do this as lightweight and as quickly as possible and I'm sending the data over a local network anyway. I'm not uploading it to a server, I'm sending it to another application I made.